# trying to sign into a bank account with headless browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, onlinebanking

I'm trying to use a puppeteer to access my bank in this scenario capital one. Although when I try I get "There was an issue accessing your account, please try again, if you continue to see this message, give us a call so we can help." I'm not too surprised that they don't appreciate me trying to log in with a headless browser.

this is the code I'm using

```js
async function credit(creditcost) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.capitalone.com/');
    await page.mouse.click(167, 121, {button: 'left'})
    await page.keyboard.type('username')
    await page.mouse.click(431, 123, {button: 'left'})
    await page.keyboard.type('password')
    await page.mouse.click(672, 121, {button: 'left'})
    await delay(5000);
    
    
    await page.screenshot({ path: './test/example.png' });
    await browser.close();
  }
```

Is there any way to get around this issue, or a possibly better option? I'm trying to get balances and transfer funds.

Comment: if it's headless, how do you know your mouse co-ordinates are correct?

Comment: Wont they be checking that the event came from a genuine click? e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted